# UIView Rotation No XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, xib

I have a simple window based ipad app with no extra xibs or classes, just your app delegate .h and .m.

I have successfully added a UIView as a subview to 'window' but it has no rotation. How can I get a view added with working rotation. (No extra xib files if possible.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom view controller for your view that implements the method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation`. Return `YES` for every orientation you wish to allow rotation to.